# 'hidden' does not work when combining Angular with Semantic UI

Tags: angular, semantic-ui

I use angular 4 in combination with Semantic UI. The following code works, if I use other classes:

```
<form class="ui form" #transactionForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <h3 class="ui header">Add a Transaction</h3>

  <div class="ui form error">
    <div class="field">
      <label>Title</label>
      <input type="text"
             class="form-control"
             id="title"
             name="title"
             #newtitle="ngModel"
             placeholder="Title"
             [(ngModel)]="title"
             required>{{newtitle.className}}
    </div>{{newtitle.valid}}
    <div [hidden]="newtitle.valid || newtitle.pristine" class="ui error message" #joh>
      <div class="header">Action Forbidden</div>
      <p>This is the error message.</p>
    </div>
    {{joh.hidden}}
  </div>
</form>
```

However: With how it is now, the `ui error message` won't get hidden. Can anyone explain why?

I put some verifications to see if the attributes really are correct. It seems to be a semantic UI problem.

The error-message should only show if the title field is empty. But it never hides.

Comment: If you touch the control it won't be pristine anymore. For your info you should read component events.

Answer (score 0):

I workarounded it with `*ngIf`. Works flawlessly:

```
<div *ngIf="(!newtitle.valid && !newtitle.pristine)" class="ui error message">
  <p>Title must be set.</p>
</div>
```